# Анимированные элементы в WPF C# приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

С помощью каких библиотек можно реализовать что-то [подобное](http://g.recordit.co/jc1UFSLeSe.gif)?

Качество гифки оставляет желать лучшего, но надеюсь суть видна. 
Мне нужно достичь такого же эффекта свечения элемента.

Comment: Вот прямо такое с разлетающимися искорками и бликами? Обычная подсветка и движение объектов можно реализовать с помощью встроенных средств анимации и стилей. А точно такое, как вы хотите можно реализовать только с помощью DirectX или OpenGL, да это и видно, что такая анимации взята из интерфейса какой-то игры.

Comment: ...вопрос слишком размытый

Comment: Да я бы не сказал, что размытый. Вполне конкретный. И да, это из игры. Ну а можно ли использовать DirectX в C# WPF приложении?

Comment: не совсем понятно с чем именно возникли затруднения

Comment: Затруднения возникли с тем, что я не могу найти нужные библиотеки или фреймворки для реализации подобных эффектов на C#